# Breeze pinv (Moore-Penrose) pseudo-inverse function gives OutOfMemory error using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix, out-of-memory

I am developing an extreme learning machine type of neural network in Spark which requires use of the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse function. This is not available in any of the Spark libraries so I'm using Breeze, which has required conversion of the Spark data structures to Breeze matrices. When I get as far as `beta = pinv(H) * T` everything fails with an OOM exception (which I didn't think was possible in Spark). Any ideas why?

`pinv` is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse in Breeze. H is a matrix of 35,000 rows and 10 columns. The SVD should be able to cope with this. It's not a particularly large dataset, only takes up 30Mb. I'm running everything locally on my laptop, nothing in the cloud. I have 8G memory on my laptop (MacBook Air).

I read that you can increase the driver memory using a spark-shell command but I don't know how to do this, or how it would link with the code in my IDE which sets up the SparkSession

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("ELMPipelineTest")
  .getOrCreate()`
```

Comment: OK thanks ... so what next, do you think? Are you saying this is too big to work on my laptop? SVD is essential to the algorithm and without it, it won't work. Do you think increasing the driver memory will make a difference? I really don't know how to change the memory, the instructions are pretty opaque for a beginner. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this as follows. Firstly the application must be run on the command line, not through the IDE, as changing the Spark driver memory must be done before the JVM is built. I'm using sbt as my build tool, so from the top level director of my project, via the Linux shell I ran:

```
sbt compile
sbt package // this creates a jar file
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class dev.elm.ELMPipeline --master  local[4] --driver-memory 8G path/to/jar.jar
```

I set $SPARK_HOME as the spark home variable first.
That avoids the Java OOM error. Thanks to @RafalKwasny for pointing this out.